# Filter date range in pandas raised `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to filter the dataframe by using a date range, where I have the initial `start_date` and the `end_date` is x days after the `start_date`. Basically, what I want is equal to the WHERE `date` BETWEEN `start_date` AND `DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL x DAYS) AS end_date` Clause in SQL.

Here is an example of my dataframe

```
+-----------+-----------+
| date      | aggregate |
+-----------+-----------+
| ...       | ...       |
|2022-08-31 | 42        |
|2022-09-01 | 30        |
|2022-09-02 | 65        |
|2022-09-03 | 55        |
| ...       | ...       |
+-----------+-----------+
```

So, I tried this on python

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = datetime.strptime("2022-08-31", "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=3) # let say I want to have 3 days range

df_filtered = df[(df['date'] >= start_date ) & (df['date'] < end_date ]
```

But, it raised `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.` and yielded a dataframe with missing several dates.

Comment: You can also use [pd.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about set the date column as the index then filter:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2022-08-31',42],
    ['2022-09-01',30],
    ['2022-09-02',65],
    ['2022-09-03',55],
],columns=['date','aggregate'])

df.date=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date',inplace=True)
start_date = datetime.strptime("2022-08-31", "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=3) # let say I want to have 3 days range
df[(df.index >= start_date ) & (df.index < end_date)]


aggregate
date    
2022-08-31  42
2022-09-01  30
2022-09-02  65
```

Comment: This is weird, I rerun your code above, and it works just fine. Then I tried to replicate it to my dataframe and it raised `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'`

Comment: ![image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwhb8.png)

Comment: Ok, I made it works. I need to parse my date column when reading the initial dataframe. Something like 

`df = pd.read_csv("x.csv", parse_dates=["date_gmt7"])`

Thanks!